# Selenium WebDriver | find_elements return only one result

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scrape google search results using python and selenium webdriver and can't figure out why the function **find_elements** returns only one element from the class (there are multiple h3 elements in the class, each one contains different title).

```
    for element in driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@class="v7W49e"]'):
    title = element.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//h3').text
    print(title)
```

[Link to Webpage Inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMg26.png)

The function don't return any error, just the title of the first result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search for element(s) inside another element you should use XPath starting with a dot `.` Otherwise Selenium will return you the first element in the DOM matching the passed locator, `//h3` in this case.
So, your code here can be as following:

```py
for element in driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@class="v7W49e"]'):
    title = element.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='.//h3').text
    print(title)
```

**UPD**
There is only one element matching `//*[@class='v7W49e']` XPath locator there so `driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@class="v7W49e"]')` will always return you a single web element.
You should use `//*[@class='v7W49e']//h3` there instead.
This code will work much better.
It is still not good enough since not all the elements matching `//*[@class='v7W49e']//h3` XPath locator will have text to show you, but this will give you multiple results.

```py
for element in driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@class="v7W49e"]//h3'):
    title = element.text
    print(title)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I've tried to add the a dot to the code and I'm still getting back only one element from the function.
I'm suspecting that the problem maybe related of the way I used "find elements". I've tried to set the result of the function as a variable and print it, and the variable only printed one element.

Comment: Please see the updated answer and let me know if now it worked for you